# Is it a good idea to have a null block in my code

Tags: c

I have a situation where i define my variables within the loop

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   if()
   {
      // Do some stuff
   }
   else
   {
      char *a[] = { };// Initialize my array
      char *b[] = { };// Initialize my array
   }
}
```

Now the question is I define my variables when needed that is in the else case.
I can't extend the scope of these variables outside the `for` loop(My design is such)

So is it a good idea to have

```
{
   char *a[] = { };// Initialize my array
   char *b[] = { };// Initialize my array
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       if()
       {
         // Do stuff
       }
       else
       {
           // Use a and b here
       }
   }
}
```

By having a block as shown above I am avoiding defining the variables in each iteration. I want to know which is a better option and why?

So just to avoid initialization of my array in each iteration I am planning to move them out of the loop and create a block as shown above. 
Why initialize the same array with same values in each iteration ? Aren't we consuming CPU cycles? Instead of this I can just create a block and move it outside ? Isn't this a good idea?

Comment: Are you stuck on C89? Variable declarations don't all have to go at the start of a block in modern C.

Comment: Define variables in the scope they are needed. Are they needed outside of the `for` loop? Then define them outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg They should not be visible outside the `for` loop so can I make a block as shown above is my question

Comment: Yes, your second approach is valid C.

Comment: @alk Thank you sir. I just wanted this. Just to add can I just go ahead and use it ? Because I see a advantage of using it over the first approach ?

Comment: What makes you doubt?

Comment: @alk I totally understand that is how it should be done !! But I wanted to know is there a better way or are there any issues doing so.. Anyways my approach was right and I will stick to it

Comment: You'll have to realize that on modern compilers, stacking and unstacking doesn't necessarily happen at the line where the variable is declared. Far more likely, stacking happens just before the first time that variable is used, and unstacking happens just after the last time it was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if a variable declaration sits inside a loop:

```
for(;;)
{
     int a;
     int b = 99;
     // more code using a and b
}
```

this is (conceptually) *moved* by the compiler outside of the loop:

```
int a, b;
for(;;)
{
     b = 99;
     // more code using a and b
}
```

So, it does **not cost anything** to have the variable declarations close to the usage of the variables to make the code as clear and readable as possible.

To answer your question: Introducing additional block levels is therefore not necessary.

Note: Declarations do not use any CPU cycles because these things are handled at startup of the program or by some reservations of stack space at method invocation. **Initializations do cost some cycles**, but these are not moved anyway.

---

**Edit**

If a fresh initialization is required at the beginning of **each iteration** of a loop it must happen at the beginnig of the loop.

If such an initialization is not necessary id **should** be moved outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being sensible and answering. I wanted to know whether the initialization is also moved outside the `for()` loop by compiler?which is a right place to keep my intiialization in this case?

Comment: As you can see in my answer, _initializations_ stay. They need to be done for each iteration (otherwise the program logic changes).

Comment: Since initialization is not moved outside I can keep it within the loop ? Is there no harm doing so I mean keeping the initialization inside the `for` loop? In each iteration I do the same initialization somehow I feel that is not a good idea so I thought of introducing a block as shown above. Thanks for answering though

Comment: This is another, different question. If your logic requires an initialization at **each iteration** then it should be inside the loop, otherwise not. (Initializations uses CPU cycles)

Comment: Yeah I think I didn't put my question is right words. But I wanted to know where to keep my initializations. To add to this , why initialize the same array with same values in each iteration ? Aren't we consuming CPU cycles? Instead of this I can just create a block and move it outside

Comment: If your logic does not require a fresh initialization at each iteration then you should move it outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

#### Step 1

Write your code in the clearest, most understandable manner possible.

#### Step 2

Profile your code.

#### Step 3

Optimize the hot spots if necessary.